# Wordpress wrong timezone in timestamp tag

Tags: php, wordpress, date, datetime, timezone

I use following code to create a `custom tag` named `_datetime` in wordpress `function.php`.

```
function add_custom_mail_tag( $custom_mail_tags, $form_id ) {

   $custom_mail_tags[] = "_datetime";

   return $custom_mail_tags;
}
add_filter( "wpcf7_special_mail_tags", function( $output, $name, $html ) {
   if ( $name === "_datetime" ) {
      $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
      if ( $timestamp = $submission->get_meta( 'timestamp' ) ) {
         $date = date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), $timestamp );
         $time = date_i18n( get_option( 'time_format' ), $timestamp );
         $date_time = $date . " " . $time;
         return $date_time;
      }
   }
   return $output;
}, 10, 3 );
```

However, the timezone is wrong and even though I've set a timezone on wordpress under `Setting>General>timezone`, it keeps sending timezone in UTC.

Another predefined tag of this plugin works OK and send time in correct format, but this function just sends in UTC.

How can I modify it to send the correct timezone set by wordpress?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

I replaced `date_i18n` with `wp_date` and it solved the problem.
Also note that `date_i18n()` is now deprecated in favor of `wp_date()` as also reported in the article below.

https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/09/23/date-time-improvements-wp-5-3/